# Pad an array by the values in the array (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I currently have a numpy array of numbers. For example, let's say I have:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6]
```

I want to have a new array where each element is repeated by the amount of its value. So for this example, I would get:

```
[1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

However, I would rather not have to loop through this array and was wondering if there is a function in numpy or some quick process for doing this certain process? Thanks!

Comment: is a list comprehension considered looping in your opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6])
np.repeat(a, a)
```

output

```
array([1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) in conjunction with a list-comprehension.

```
from itertools import chain

list(chain.from_iterable([item] * item for item in data))

[1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,3,4])
b = np.repeat(a,a)
```